How to use Eslint rule for JSX attribute value
I want to apply eslint rule for JSX attribute value.
like I have a component having some attribute for example
<Component
  attribute1="abc-efg"
/>

In above example I want to place a rule which will check that if attribute1 is having values in lower-case and kebab-case if the value is other then that error will be thrown.
I tried: @typescript-eslint/naming-convention
but not able to achieve anything.

To enforce a rule that checks if JSX attribute values are in lowercase and kebab-case, you can create a custom ESLint rule using the eslint-plugin and @typescript-eslint libraries. Here’s how you can set it up:
// .eslintrc.js or eslint.config.js

module.exports = {
  // Other ESLint configurations
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['*.tsx', '*.jsx'], // Apply rule to JSX and TSX files
      rules: {
        'jsx-attributes/lowercase-kebab-case': ['error', { allowedAttributes: ['attribute1'] }],
      },
    },
  ],
};

After setting up the rule, run ESLint in your project to enforce the rule:
eslint --ext .jsx,.tsx src

I tested some JSX code with eslint with your requirement, and it worked for me.

// enforce-foo-bar.js

module.exports = {
  meta: {
    type: 'problem',
    docs: {
      description:
        "This rule enforces that the value of the attribute is in kebab case or camel case",
    },
    fixable: 'code',
    schema: [],
  },
  create(context) {
    return {
      JSXOpeningElement(node) {
        const attributes = node.attributes;

        if (attributes.length > 0) {
          for (const element of attributes) {
            const attributeValue = element.value.value;

            if (attributeValue) {
              if (
                attributeValue.match(/^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$/) ||
                attributeValue.match(/^[a-z][a-z0-9-]*$/)
              ) {
                context.report({
                  node: element,
                  message: 'Value in kebab case or camel case',
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
    };
  },
};

// eslint-plugin-example.js:

const fooBarRule = require('./enforce-foo-bar');
const plugin = { rules: { 'enforce-foo-bar': fooBarRule } };
module.exports = plugin;

// eslint.config.js:

'use strict';

const eslintPluginExample = require('./eslint-plugin-example');

module.exports = [
  {
    files: ['**/*.jsx'],
    languageOptions: {
      sourceType: 'module',
      ecmaVersion: 'latest',
      parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
          jsx: true,
        },
      },
    },

    plugins: { example: eslintPluginExample },
    rules: {
      'example/enforce-foo-bar': 'error',
    },
  },
];


// Greeting.jsx

import React from 'react';

export default function Greeting({ name, age, location }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hello, {name}!</p>
      <p>Age: {age}</p>
      <p>Location: {location}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

// Test.jsx

import React from 'react';
import Greeting from './Greeting';

export default function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Down</h1>
      <Greeting name='John' location='new-york' age={30}  />
    </div>
  );
}

After setting up the file structure, run npx eslint Test.jsx

sources

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/extend/custom-rule-tutorial
https://blog.maximeheckel.com/posts/how-to-build-first-eslint-rule/
https://astexplorer.net/
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-control-regex

